# change image resolution

Tags: html

I am trying to switch between different resolutions (original-standard-high) of an image using ONLY one image. Is this possible using any way?
Here is an example of what I want, but it is using three image with three different resolutions, I want to use only one image. http://www.biomedcentral.com/1741-7007/8/59

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>resize image </title>
<style> 
.high{width:500px; image-resolution:300dpi; } 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img   class="high" src="original.jpg" border="0" /><!-- the  orginal image width =100 px-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply manipulate the *display size* of the image using the `width` and `height` CSS or HTML attributes. This won't change the actual resolution of the image, it will just display it smaller or larger. This is not usually beneficial since the large image will always be downloaded and possibly waste a lot of bandwidth and slow down the browser (unless you're certain it will be viewed anyway, then it can be beneficial).

If you simply don't want to create a bunch of small and large versions of the same file, look into resizing the images on-the-fly using a server-side language.

Comment: I'm  trying to use **image-resolution** **CSS** property introduced in **HTML5** to fix the stretching problem, but unfortunately it doesn't work at all on any browser

Comment: @loll An image usually only has *one* resolution. Also, don't confuse *resolution* (dpi) with *dimensions* (width, height). What exactly do you want to achieve? I couldn't gain anything from your linked example.

Comment: well, I want to change image resolution(dpi), using any way javascript, css, java, or any other technique

Comment: @loll That's not possible, or at least it wouldn't have any meaningful impact. Take a step back, what is it you *really* want? Click on an image to have it display larger?

Comment: @loll Then you want to change the *dimensions*, not the dpi. As was said before, you could have one large image which you display smaller than it really is by setting `width` and `height` attributes. That's wasteful though since the client will always have to download the large resolution, which he may not need. There's a reason why everybody is using a separate smaller thumbnail version of large images.

Comment: @loll If you want your image at its largest display to be 800px wide, then you need an image that is 800px wide, and downscale to the smaller sizes as necessary. You can't start off with a 400px-wide image and display it 800px wide without losing quality.

Comment: well I can see what you say, but when we open photoshop for example and change the image resolution in (pixel/inch) or (pixel/cm), you can see that image dimensions will be changed automatically, and that's what I want, u get it?

Comment: Yes, but you lose quality when you increase an image from 72dpi to 300 dpi (say). You can't get something for nothing. When you display an image at a bigger size in a browser it's upsampling it like Photoshop does. Some browsers will do this better than others, but it will still be blurry.

Comment: @loll Assume you have an image 2x2 pixels in size. That's 4 pixels, at most 4 different bits of color. Do you think you can simply increase the resolution and get a print-quality version of the Mona Lisa out of those 4 pixels? As @Skilldrick said, what ain't there simply ain't there.

Comment: yes you are right, It's impossible to do some thing like this.BIG THANKS for your great help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in HTML/CSS by setting the image size. Beware though, that some browsers do scaling better than others (for example, earlier versions of IE do no anti-aliasing, which makes scaled images look jagged).

Also, do you really want your users to download all the images on your page at maximum res before they can see the thumbnails? This is a big waste of bandwidth if they'll generally only need to look at a few images at full size.

Comment: well, I tried to do this exactly by HTML/CSS but the image in high resolution looks like stretched, I want a way to keep my image in a good view, u get it?

Comment: You need to make the high resolution image the right size, then downscale the medium and small ones.

Comment: yes you are right, but actually I have my already Existing images , with small size

Comment: You can't make a small image big without losing quality - it's impossible.

Comment: I hope to find a way to change image resolution, if so , the quality will be the same.

Comment: You just cannot do it.  Once you made the image small, that information is lost.  This isn't CSI, it's the real world ;)  Host your big pictures and display them smaller for thumbnails.  

Of course, it makes a lot more sense to host two versions; that's what thumbnails were intended to do.

Comment: @Joeri +1 "This isn't CSI": One of my pet peeves.